# Python String slicing results unpredictable or same at different slice indices

Tags: python, string, slice

I have a string "Queen" and I have the following code snippet:

```
    string = "Queen"
    print(string[::-1])
```

Surprisingly it gives the result "neeuQ". But when I do `print(string[-1::0])`
it says

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-26-3b86270ea57d> in <module>
          1 string = "Queen"
    ----> 2 print(string[-1::0])
    
    ValueError: slice step cannot be zero
```

Again when I write `print(string[-1::9])` or any other number>0 it shows the same result "n".

I understand this is about Python's string slicing properties but I didn't get the operations that are happening inside for every command. Normally for a `string[0::4]` it's absolutely fine but what's happening in these cases? Why are we having such outputs?

Comment: Do you know what the 3 numbers in the slice mean? What is a step length of 0 supposed to be?

Comment: @schwobaseggl No I don't.. I am new to Python. Can you please help?